# Merging static table view with a UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm currently trying to build a screen that contains 2 `UIButton`, and 1 `UIImageView`.

**Below these UI Elements, I want to add a static table view that would contain 1 `UITextField` for each cell in order to create a kind of scrollable form.**

The error I'm having is the following one:

> Static table views are only valid when embedded in `UITableViewController` instances

While it doesn't seem possible to create a static table view without a table view controller, I was wondering if there could be any way to get the same result as my initial idea?

Please note that I'm building my UI using storyboard.

Here's a screenshot of what I was trying to build initially:

[image: (Here's a screenshot of what I was trying to build initially)]

EDIT: I finally decided to use a static view controller, and implemented the buttons in a cell and the other textfields in different cells. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Feed us with some code.

Comment: Hello Marco, as I built the entire view using the storyboard, everything that is linked to the UI is exactly as represented on the screenshot link I posted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh6jC.png

Comment: Try dragging `UITableView` to a `ViewController` instead of using a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: @Koh Unfortunately that is what I’ve tried :( (As shown on the screenshot)

Comment: @Unknown_ Have you tried [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55905033/2229783)? I guess it solves the problem you described in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `UITableViewController` as a childViewController to your bigger `UIViewController` (parentVC)

Then manage parentVC's view hierarchy so that you can achieve the 2 `UIButton`, 1 `UIImageView` and a table view at the bottom

Comment: Well, it would be a nice solution. I think, you could just make a demo project and provide that as a reference to help the OP.

Comment: Hello Joshua, as I'm still a beginner in IOS, How am I supposed to ass the UITableViewController as a childViewController to a UIViewController ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 10.2 you can use `Container View` to implement the UI you described. Drag and drop a container view object to the required view controller in your storyboard scene:

[image: container view]

[image: a view controller with a container view object]

Then add `UITableViewController` instance to your storyboard scene:

[image: UITableViewController]

Set `Static Cells` for it's `Content`:

[image: Static Cells]

Then right-click on `Content View` that you added in one of the previous steps, and setup it as described on the following screenshots:

[image: Setup Container View 1]
[image: Setup Container View 2]
[image: Setup Container View 3]

Setup constrains and cells content. Then you will see something like that on your testing device:

[image: Running on device]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should manage this adding elements in a `UIScrollView`, there's no need to use a `UITableView`. So you can scroll all the contents when you show the keyboard

Comment: Hello Alastar, A few days ago I actually figured out that it was possible to use Static table views to make a scrollable form, can you explain to me why it would be better to use UIScrollView ? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

A static tableview is nothing more than a `UITableViewController` handling the `UITableView`'s `UITableViewDataSource` methods on your behalf.

You can simply add a `UITableView` to your `UIViewController`, set the `UITableView` datasource to your `UIViewController` and implement the methods as appropriate.

e.g.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.datasource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // create UITableViewCell
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you paid attention to this sentence: ___Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances___?

Comment: @nayem yes, you missed my first sentence in my answer. The implementation of a static tableview is nothing more than the combination of a UITableViewController, holding a UITableView and supplying the numbers to these delegate functions. When you ask a storyboard for a static tableview, all it is doing is passing these numbers into the `init(withCoder` function and then the controller passes them to the delegate functions. Any class of any kind can achieve the same result, by doing exactly what the storyboard is doing. Simply suppling the answers to the datasource functions

Comment: Hello Simon I have tried your solution but the error is this the same :(

Comment: @Unknown_ I believe you've misunderstood and made a mistake. As your error message tells you, you can NOT have a static tableView outside of a UITableViewController. There is no way around this. You must either do what I have suggested above, or what the other answer says, using child viewControllers. For my solution, drag the UITableView onto your viewController, do NOT set it to static, create an outlet named `tableView` and then follow my instructions above. This will give you the tableView that you want, without using static. This is what the static setting is doing for you

Comment: This answer amounts to saying "just use a dynamic table view instead". You gain none of the usual advantages of a static table view by doing this.

Comment: @EthanHolshouser yes, because the OP was asking for how to have a static tableview on half of a UIViewController, which is not possible. At the time, based on the info the poster provided, it seemed like there were only 2 options. 1) as other answers have suggested, to wrap it in a container view, or 2) what I have suggested to simply use a dynamic tableview. Given those two choices, I think its a much bigger disadvantage to have multiple UIViewControllers, multiple lifecycle events and a much heavier screen ... in order to avoid adding the 4 protocol methods to make it dynamic